# How to arrange dataset in the Apriori template?

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, apriori

I am trying to run apriori algorithm on my dataset (shown on picture below).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkTF5.png]

My present data set is as per image which has information about SAP ID & alarm code.

I need to transform the dataset as per the format discussed in the tutorial (each SAP ID should have list of all respective alarms). See Capture 2 image below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdNQX.png]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Do a *pivot* operation.

That will bring your data into the desired form.